# javamail part downloaded is different than original gmail message content

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

I am implementing a emailclient with javamail (imap).

There is a "part" of an email where the content is (at one point only) different from what i see on the original email in gmail. This leads to a broken link, in the example a link with two points.

The message is printed to the console with part.writeTo(System.out);

How can that be.. any idea what goes wrong? Help appreciated!

[image]

```
// MimeMessage  
if(part.getContentType().toLowerCase().startsWith("text/html")) {
                    
    // both, (String)part.getContent() and MimeUtility.decode as below
    // and also writeTo contains the additional point..

    part.writeTo(System.out);
    // htmltext.append((String)part.getContent());
    String body = IOUtils.toString(MimeUtility.decode(new ByteArrayInputStream(((String)part.getContent()).getBytes()), "quoted-printable"),"UTF-8");
    htmltext.append(body);
}
```

All other mails are fetched correctly.

Comment: Did you receive this email via IMAP or SMTP?  Or did you use a serializer that is preparing it for SMTP?  SMTP does "dot stuffing" if a line begins with ., but this should be transparent to IMAP.

Comment: It would be helpful for more information on exactly how this message got into your system.

Comment: Its fetched via imap. No serializer used. No sending, no smtp. Yep, should be transparent but its not. Asking for why could it be?

Comment: It looks like a bug in the gmail IMAP implementation.  It might be good to check with another test message and like, socat to see if it does this stuffing or if something else in the pipeline has added it; or if happens for ‘RFC822’, or just for part fetches like ‘1.2’  If it does, you could detect it and “fix” it.  I double checked and there’s nothing in the IMAP RFC that I can find that indicates that dot stuffing should be used; POP3 may do dot stuffing if you’re accidentally using that protocol, but the protocol handler should remove that.